# Examine convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(e-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n)^\alpha$ depening on $\alpha$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine for what $\alpha$ following series converge:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big(e-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\Big)^\alpha
$$

I tried to do it by using following ineqaulity:
$$
1+1+\frac{1}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n< e-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n<(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1}-(1+\frac{1}{n})^n
$$
Right side of it is easy to operate, but I don't know how to procceed with left side of this inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this as

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[e-\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n\right]^\alpha=e^\alpha\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-a_n)^\alpha,$$

where

$$a_n = e^{-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n.$$

Note that $0 < a_n < 1 $ and $a_n \to 1$ as $n \to \infty.$

Using the inequality $x < -\ln(1-x) < x/(1-x)$ for $0 < x < 1$, we have

$$1-a_n < -\ln a_n = -\ln (1 - (1-a_n))< \frac{1-a_n}{a_n}.$$

Hence,

$$ 1 < \frac{-\ln a_n}{1-a_n} < \frac{1}{a_n}.$$

It follows from the Squeeze Theorem that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{-\ln a_n}{1-a_n} = 1.$$

Therefore, the original series converges if and only if we have convergence of the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\ln a_n)^\alpha.$$

Using the Taylor series expansion $\ln(1+x) = x - x^2 /2 +O(x^3)$, it is easy to show that

$$(-\ln a_n)^\alpha = [1 - n \ln (1 + 1/n)]^\alpha \sim (1/2n)^\alpha.$$

Therefore, the series converges for $\alpha > 1$ and diverges for $\alpha \leqslant 1$.